# ngx-timeago breaks when trying to deploy angular app

Tags: angular

If I build locally, everything is fine...

Yet, aws code build doing this on a docker image with `npx ng build`, I get:

```
#25 41.40 ./node_modules/ngx-timeago/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngx-timeago.js:439:76-112 - Error: export 'ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef' (imported as 'ɵngcc0') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ContentChild, ContentChildren, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, DebugElement, DebugEventListener, DebugNode, DefaultIterableDiffer, Directive, ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER, ElementRef, EmbeddedViewRef, EnvironmentInjector, ErrorHandler, EventEmitter, Host, HostBinding, HostListener, INJECTOR, Inject, InjectFlags, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Input, IterableDiffers, KeyValueDiffers, LOCALE_ID, MissingTranslationStrategy, ModuleWithComponentFactories, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, NgModuleRef, NgProbeToken, NgZone, Optional, Output, PACKAGE_ROOT_URL, PLATFORM_ID, PLATFORM_INITIALIZER, Pipe, PlatformRef, Query, QueryList, ReflectiveInjector, ReflectiveKey, Renderer2, RendererFactory2, RendererStyleFlags2, ResolvedReflectiveFactory, Sanitizer, SecurityContext, Self, SimpleChange, SkipSelf, TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, TemplateRef, Testability, TestabilityRegistry, Type, VERSION, Version, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation, ViewRef, asNativeElements, assertPlatform, createComponent, createEnvironmentInjector, createNgModule, createNgModuleRef, createPlatform, createPlatformFactory, defineInjectable, destroyPlatform, enableProdMode, forwardRef, getDebugNode, getModuleFactory, getNgModuleById, getPlatform, importProvidersFrom, inject, isDevMode, platformCore, reflectComponentType, resolveForwardRef, setTestabilityGetter, ɵALLOW_MULTIPLE_PLATFORMS, ɵAPP_ID_RANDOM_PROVIDER, ɵChangeDetectorStatus, ɵComponentFactory, ɵConsole, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵINJECTOR_SCOPE, ɵLContext, ɵLifecycleHooksFeature, ɵLocaleDataIndex, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵNG_ELEMENT_ID, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵNG_PROV_DEF, ɵNOT_FOUND_CHECK_ONLY_ELEMENT_INJECTOR, ɵNO_CHANGE, ɵNgModuleFactory, ɵNoopNgZone, ɵReflectionCapabilities, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵRender3ComponentRef, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ɵRuntimeError, ɵTESTABILITY, ɵTESTABILITY_GETTER, ɵViewRef, ɵ_sanitizeHtml, ɵ_sanitizeUrl, ɵallowSanitizationBypassAndThrow, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustHtml, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustResourceUrl, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustScript, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustStyle, ɵbypassSanitizationTrustUrl, ɵclearResolutionOfComponentResourcesQueue, ɵcoerceToBoolean, ɵcompileComponent, ɵcompileDirective, ɵcompileNgModule, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, ɵcompileNgModuleFactory, ɵcompilePipe, ɵcreateInjector, ɵdefaultIterableDiffers, ɵdefaultKeyValueDiffers, ɵdetectChanges, ɵdevModeEqual, ɵfindLocaleData, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible, ɵformatRuntimeError, ɵgetDebugNode, ɵgetDebugNodeR2, ɵgetDirectives, ɵgetHostElement, ɵgetInjectableDef, ɵgetLContext, ɵgetLocaleCurrencyCode, ɵgetLocalePluralCase, ɵgetSanitizationBypassType, ɵgetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵgetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵglobal, ɵinjectChangeDetectorRef, ɵinternalCreateApplication, ɵisBoundToModule, ɵisDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy, ɵisInjectable, ɵisListLikeIterable, ɵisObservable, ɵisPromise, ɵisStandalone, ɵisSubscribable, ɵivyEnabled, ɵmakeDecorator, ɵnoSideEffects, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵpublishDefaultGlobalUtils, ɵpublishGlobalUtil, ɵregisterLocaleData, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵresetJitOptions, ɵresolveComponentResources, ɵsetAllowDuplicateNgModuleIdsForTest, ɵsetClassMetadata, ɵsetCurrentInjector, ɵsetDocument, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵsetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵsetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵstore, ɵstringify, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵunregisterLocaleData, ɵunwrapSafeValue, ɵɵCopyDefinitionFeature, ɵɵFactoryTarget, ɵɵInheritDefinitionFeature, ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature, ɵɵProvidersFeature, ɵɵStandaloneFeature, ɵɵadvance, ɵɵattribute, ɵɵattributeInterpolate1, ɵɵattributeInterpolate2, ɵɵattributeInterpolate3, ɵɵattributeInterpolate4, ɵɵattributeInterpolate5, ɵɵattributeInterpolate6, ɵɵattributeInterpolate7, ɵɵattributeInterpolate8, ɵɵattributeInterpolateV, ɵɵclassMap, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate1, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate2, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate3, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate4, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate5, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate6, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate7, ɵɵclassMapInterpolate8, ɵɵclassMapInterpolateV, ɵɵclassProp, ɵɵcontentQuery, ɵɵdefineComponent, ɵɵdefineDirective, ɵɵdefineInjectable, ɵɵdefineInjector, ɵɵdefineNgModule, ɵɵdefinePipe, ɵɵdirectiveInject, ɵɵdisableBindings, ɵɵelement, ɵɵelementContainer, ɵɵelementContainerEnd, ɵɵelementContainerStart, ɵɵelementEnd, ɵɵelementStart, ɵɵenableBindings, ɵɵgetCurrentView, ɵɵgetInheritedFactory, ɵɵhostProperty, ɵɵi18n, ɵɵi18nApply, ɵɵi18nAttributes, ɵɵi18nEnd, ɵɵi18nExp, ɵɵi18nPostprocess, ɵɵi18nStart, ɵɵinject, ɵɵinjectAttribute, ɵɵinvalidFactory, ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep, ɵɵlistener, ɵɵloadQuery, ɵɵnamespaceHTML, ɵɵnamespaceMathML, ɵɵnamespaceSVG, ɵɵnextContext, ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata, ɵɵngDeclareComponent, ɵɵngDeclareDirective, ɵɵngDeclareFactory, ɵɵngDeclareInjectable, ɵɵngDeclareInjector, ɵɵngDeclareNgModule, ɵɵngDeclarePipe, ɵɵpipe, ɵɵpipeBind1, ɵɵpipeBind2, ɵɵpipeBind3, ɵɵpipeBind4, ɵɵpipeBindV, ɵɵprojection, ɵɵprojectionDef, ɵɵproperty, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate1, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate2, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate3, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate4, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate5, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate6, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate7, ɵɵpropertyInterpolate8, ɵɵpropertyInterpolateV, ɵɵpureFunction0, ɵɵpureFunction1, ɵɵpureFunction2, ɵɵpureFunction3, ɵɵpureFunction4, ɵɵpureFunction5, ɵɵpureFunction6, ɵɵpureFunction7, ɵɵpureFunction8, ɵɵpureFunctionV, ɵɵqueryRefresh, ɵɵreference, ɵɵregisterNgModuleType, ɵɵresetView, ɵɵresolveBody, ɵɵresolveDocument, ɵɵresolveWindow, ɵɵrestoreView, ɵɵsanitizeHtml, ɵɵsanitizeResourceUrl, ɵɵsanitizeScript, ɵɵsanitizeStyle, ɵɵsanitizeUrl, ɵɵsanitizeUrlOrResourceUrl, ɵɵsetComponentScope, ɵɵsetNgModuleScope, ɵɵstyleMap, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate1, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate2, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate3, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate4, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate5, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate6, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate7, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolate8, ɵɵstyleMapInterpolateV, ɵɵstyleProp, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate1, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate2, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate3, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate4, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate5, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate6, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate7, ɵɵstylePropInterpolate8, ɵɵstylePropInterpolateV, ɵɵsyntheticHostListener, ɵɵsyntheticHostProperty, ɵɵtemplate, ɵɵtemplateRefExtractor, ɵɵtext, ɵɵtextInterpolate, ɵɵtextInterpolate1, ɵɵtextInterpolate2, ɵɵtextInterpolate3, ɵɵtextInterpolate4, ɵɵtextInterpolate5, ɵɵtextInterpolate6, ɵɵtextInterpolate7, ɵɵtextInterpolate8, ɵɵtextInterpolateV, ɵɵtrustConstantHtml, ɵɵtrustConstantResourceUrl, ɵɵviewQuery)
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.clock.d.ts:8:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 8     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoDefaultClock, never>;
#25 41.40                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.clock.d.ts:9:26 - error TS2724: '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 9     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<TimeagoDefaultClock>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.directive.d.ts:31:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 31     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoDirective, [{ optional: true; }, null, null, null, null]>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.directive.d.ts:32:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵDirectiveDefWithMeta'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 32     static ɵdir: ɵngcc0.ɵɵDirectiveDefWithMeta<TimeagoDirective, "[timeago]", ["timeago"], { "date": "date"; "live": "live"; }, {}, never>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.formatter.d.ts:13:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 13     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoDefaultFormatter, never>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.formatter.d.ts:14:26 - error TS2724: '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 14     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<TimeagoDefaultFormatter>;
#25 41.40                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.formatter.d.ts:31:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 31     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoCustomFormatter, never>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.formatter.d.ts:32:26 - error TS2724: '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 32     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<TimeagoCustomFormatter>;
#25 41.40                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.intl.d.ts:37:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 37     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoIntl, never>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.intl.d.ts:38:26 - error TS2724: '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 38     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<TimeagoIntl>;
#25 41.40                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.module.d.ts:19:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 19     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<TimeagoModule, [typeof ɵngcc1.TimeagoDirective, typeof ɵngcc2.TimeagoPipe], never, [typeof ɵngcc1.TimeagoDirective, typeof ɵngcc2.TimeagoPipe]>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.pipe.d.ts:24:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 24     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeagoPipe, [{ optional: true; }, null, null, null]>;
#25 41.40                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.pipe.d.ts:25:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ɵɵPipeDefWithMeta'.
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 25     static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDefWithMeta<TimeagoPipe, "timeago">;
#25 41.40                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 Error: node_modules/ngx-timeago/timeago.pipe.d.ts:26:26 - error TS2724: '"/home/app/my-app/angular-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member named 'ɵɵInjectableDef'. Did you mean 'ɵgetInjectableDef'?
#25 41.40 
#25 41.40 26     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<TimeagoPipe>;
#25 41.40                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#25 41.40
```

**update**

from package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-timeago": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^14.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.37.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "import-sort-style-module": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.34",
    "ng-packagr": "^14.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the `angular` / `ngx-timeago` version as well as post your dependency packages list.

Comment: @HariHaran ngx-timeago is `2.0.0`, and angular is `14.1.0`.  I have updated my question with the package.json

Answer (score 0):

I looks like `ngx-timeago` 2.x is not compatible with Angular 14.

You will have to change for another library or fork it to support a more recent version on Angular.